# Show that $2^n>n$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Show that $2^n>n$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

I can solve this by mathematical induction. Is there any other method to solve.

Comment: What's wrong with induction?  But, as an alternative,look at $f(x)=2^x-x$.  Then $f'(x)=2^x(\ln(2))-1$.  Can you conclude from there?

Comment: One can prove $2^x \gt x, \forall x \in R$

Comment: @EugenCovaci Would you please say me how?

Comment: Just like @lulu said in his comment

Comment: @user1942348 You can never avoid induction when using natural numbers or anything that's built from them. Whoever thinks this is true simply didn't look deep enough. Having said this, $2^n=(1+1)^n=\sum \limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}=1+n+\text{positive number}$.

Comment: @lulu Please write some more lines.

Comment: If $2^n>n$ then,$n\log_n2>1$ must hold true...

Comment: Just to be clear: $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$, right?

Comment: @GitGud, one "can never avoid induction"? That's a strong claim. Of the proofs I see on this question so far, two rely on results that are proved by induction (binomial theorem and AGM inequality), and two do not (the power-set proof and the calculus proof). Can you unpack your claim further?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Induction is part of the very definition of $\mathbb N$, see for instance [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490825/prove-the-principle-of-mathematical-induction-in-sf-zfc/490880#490880). Even conceptually, the natural numbers are the embodiment of induction. Regarding the two calculus proofs, I suppose that to determine where specifically (if at all) induction is used, I would need to know the elementary framework you're considering (your definitions of $\mathbb N$, $\mathbb R$, archimedean property, etc).

Comment: That all makes sense, but I don't see where induction comes into showing that the power set of a finite set is of greater cardinality than the original set. That doesn't even depend on the existence of any infinite set, does it?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs One would need to prove that $|P(x)| = 2^{|x|}$, for any finite set $x$. There is a direct proof for that which does not rely on induction, instead relies on the counting principle of multiplication, but it is possible that at some fundamental that relies on induction.

Comment: @BenjiAltman, the proof I know for the fundamental counting principle does rely on induction. On the other hand, if exponentiation is taken, not as repeated multiplication, but as a count of the number of functions from one set to another, that might be a way around it. To count the power set of $S$, count functions from $S$ to the set $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the binomial expansion,
$$2^n = (1+1)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n {n\choose i}\geq 1+n$$
since every term in the sum is positive, and both ${n\choose 1}=n$ and ${n\choose 0}=1$ appear in the sum.

Answer (score 8):

$${ \left( 1+1 \right)  }^{ n }=1+n+\frac { n\left( n-1 \right)  }{ 2 } +..+1>n$$

Answer (score 5):

By the [arithmetic-geometric mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means),

$$\sqrt[n]n\le{n+1+1+\cdots+1\over n}={2n-1\over n}\lt 2$$

(where the first numerator has one $n$ and $n-1$ $1$'s). Of course this leaves the question of proving AGM without using induction.

Answer (score 2):

With set theory:

Observe that $2^n$ is the cardinality of the power set of an $n$-element set. The power set of a finite set must have greater cardinality than that of the original set, because it contains all singletons, as well as the empty set, and thus has at least $n+1$ elements, which is trivially greater then $n$.

For $n>1$, the power set also contains other, larger subsets, but the proof is already complete.

Comment: It would be nice if you provided a proof that the power set of a set with cadinality $n$, where $n$ is finite, has cardinality $2^n$.

Comment: Would it work to define exponentiation as cardinal exponentiation, and note that we can identify subsets of an n-element set with functions from that set to the 2-element set $\{0,1\}$?

Answer (score 0):

With analysis:

$2^1 >1$, and for any $x>1$, $\;(2^x)'>(x)'=1$, since

- $(2^x)'=2^x\ln 2>2\ln 2=\ln4$
- $4>\mathrm e$.

Hence, by a standard corollary  of the *Mean value theorem*,  $\;2^x>x\;$ for all $\;x\ge 1$.